# Alternative to Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition) in webview in c# win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, webview

I am using

```
HtmlElement elem = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition);
```

to get element from point in web browser control. I want to get the html element on mouse click in web view.Any alternative to this in web view control

Answer (score 0):

As per the explanation here:
[Web view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/web-view)

> Interacting with web view content
>
> You can interact with the content of the web view by using the
>   InvokeScriptAsync method to invoke or inject script into the web view
>   content, and the ScriptNotify event to get information back from the
>   web view content.

So you could do something like this:

```
    private void WebView1_DOMContentLoaded(object sender, Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT.WebViewControlDOMContentLoadedEventArgs e)
        {
            String func = @" document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                             //Get the Div Tag Name and its ID as string back into our code
                             window.external.notify(e.target.tagName + '(' + e.target.id + ')');
                            });";
            webView1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", func);
        }

        private void WebView1_ScriptNotify(object sender, Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.Interop.WinRT.WebViewControlScriptNotifyEventArgs e)
        {
            string s = e.Value; //This will give you the Div Tag Name and ID
        }
```